# Parametrization of a half circle in a different interval other than from 0 to $\pi$.

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have a half circle parametrization such that $e^{it}$, $0 \leq t \leq \pi$, to get the parameterization of the same circle on interval $0 \leq t \leq 1$, is it just $e^{it\pi}, \quad 0\leq t \leq 1$?

The contour is an upper half circle centred at the origin connected to a straight line, to be parametrized from $0 \leq t \leq 2$. That's why I thought of having the interval from $0 \leq t \leq 1$. If anyone has better suggestions for parametrizing both the circle and line segment from 0 to 2 then that would be great.

This is on the complex plane.

Comment: Where do you want the half-circle? $\Re(z)>0$? $\Im(z)>0$? the opposite of these? Something else?

Comment: top half of a unit circle centred at origin

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to avoid the interval $[0,\pi]$? This of course, is the natural choice, so I hope you don't mind my asking.

Comment: How about $[\pi, 2 \pi)$?

Comment: Because that's what my prof wants haha, well its a half circle connected to a line, to be parametrized from 0 < t < 2. so hence the 0 < t < 1 thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not consider $z=e^{i\theta}$ for $2\pi\leq\theta\leq 3\pi$? Or, if you want something "less trivial," then we can consider the nondegenerate interval $[a,b]$. Since we can map this interval onto the interval $[0,\pi]$ via $\pi\left(\frac{t-a}{b-a}\right)$, we can have any interval $[a,b]$ parametrize the top half of the unit circle by
$$ \exp{i\left(\pi\frac{t-a}{b-a}\right)}.$$

In your particular case, if you're paramtrizing this circle for $0\leq t\leq 1$, then we have $$\exp\left(i(\pi\cdot t)\right).$$ Now to join the segment along the real axis, we have the parametrization $2t-3$. Thus, let's suppose you're integrating $f(z)$ over this contour. Then we have from the definition: $$\int_\Gamma f(z)\,dz=\int_0^1 f\big(e^{i\pi t}\big)\cdot i\pi e^{i\pi t}\,dt+\int_1^2f(2t-3)\cdot 2\,dt.$$I hope this helps!

Comment: this complicates trying to parametrize the line segment it connects to afterwards though.

Comment: Do you realize you can parametrize these separately? It doesn't have to be a single interval. You can parametrize the circle for $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$ and the line segment for $0\leq t\leq1$.

Comment: then where does the $0<t<2$ come into play then

Comment: So your professor is asking you to parametrize this contour, the upper half unit circle centered at the origin and the line segment joining the end of the circle on the real axis, for $0\leq t\leq 2$, right? If this is the case, then use the interval $[0,1]$ and the formula I gave above, and then parametrize the segment for $1\leq t\leq 2$, which is easy.

Comment: If all you have to do is evaluate some integral, then the parametrization doesn't matter since line integrals are well-defined.

Comment: Can you explain your formula with a concrete numbers, sorry I'm not too good with theoretic stuff :|

Comment: @DJ_: I've updated the answer; hopefully it's more clear.

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $\exp(it)$, you can use $\exp (ikt)$ over $[0,\frac \pi k]$  This should indicate many options-any continuous invertible function over $[0,\pi]$ can transform the interval to another one.  Following the comments, you can use $\exp(it-\pi )$ to get $[\pi, 2\pi)$

Comment: Well its a half circle connected to a line, to be parametrized between 0 =< t =< 2, then what do I do for the line if my interval is [0, pi/k]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that you want the semi-circle and the line to be **each** parameterised over $[0,2]$.

The semi-circle is:

$$ S(t) = \cos\tfrac{t\pi}{2} + i  \sin\tfrac{t\pi}{2}  = \exp(\tfrac{1}{2}t\pi) \quad (0 \le t \le 2)  $$

The line is

$$L(t) = (1 - \tfrac{1}{2}t)P +   \tfrac{1}{2}tQ \quad (0 \le t \le 2)$$

where the points $P$ and $Q$ are given by $P=(1,0)$, $Q=(-1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, if you want the entire contour (formed by stringing the two curves together) to be continously parameterised over $[0,2]$, then:

The semi-circle is:

$$ S(t) = \cos t\pi + i  \sin t\pi = e^{it\pi} \quad (0 \le t \le 1)  $$

The line is

$$L(t) = (2 - t)P +   (t-1)Q \quad (1 \le t \le 2)$$

where the points $P$ and $Q$ are given by $P=(-1,0)$, $Q=(1,0)$.

Or, if you want a purely complex-number-ish description, $P = -1 +0i$ and $Q = 1 + 0i$, so $L(t) = 2t - 3$, as the comment indicated.

Comment: Actually, since these are complex numbers, I think it's incorrect to write it as a coordinate (though I understand it's natural to want to identify the complex plane with $\Bbb R^2$). The point being, you're actually parametrizing between $-1$ and $1$, thus $L(t)=2t-3$.